# Custom Splash Screen not working properly in Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: boot, hdmi, video, screen, image

I have tried to add a custom splash screen to my Raspberry Pi B+, in order to replace the logs during the boot with a custom video, using the hints from the following website:

http://blog.sheasilverman.com/2013/09/adding-a-startup-movie-to-your-raspberry-pi/

which says the following:

> Hey All,
>
> So I’ve been playign with trying to do a boot image or a boot movie
>   with the Raspberry Pi for a while now, and all the comments and tips
>   keep going back to a tutorial on how to boot a static image.  It
>   works, but there are a lot of problems with it like failing gracefully
>   and not returning the console window back if you aren’t booting to X. 
>   So I decided to come up with another way.  This is based off the
>   tutorial found here:
>   http://www.edv-huber.com/index.php/problemloesungen/15-custom-splash-screen-for-raspberry-pi-raspbian
>
> Instead of using the program `fbi`, we will use `omxplayer` to
>   playback a video file while the Raspberry Pi is booting in the
>   background.
>
> First off, you will want to copy the 15 to 20 second movie file to
>   your Raspberry Pi device.  Anything shorter and the video will end
>   before it’s finished booting and you will continue to see the kernel
>   messages.  You can use any video file that `omxplayer` can play back,
>   but I like .mov and .mp4 files.
>
> You will need to edit your `/boot/cmdline.txt` file:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
> ```
>
> Add **`quiet`** to the end of the line. It will look something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait quiet
> ```
>
> Make sure that is all on one line.
>
> Press `ctrl-x`, type y to confirm save, then press enter to return to
>   the command line.
>
> Copy your video somewhere to the Raspberry Pi.  I keep mine in
>   `/home/pi/` and call the video `video.mov`
>
> You will now need to create a startup script that will run omxplayer
>   at bootup.  I have modified the script from the above link.
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/init.d/asplashscreen
>
>
> #! /bin/sh
> ### BEGIN INIT INFO
> # Provides:          asplashscreen
> # Required-Start:
> # Required-Stop:
> # Should-Start:      
> # Default-Start:     S
> # Default-Stop:
> # Short-Description: Show custom splashscreen
> # Description:       Show custom splashscreen
> ### END INIT INFO
>
> do_start () {
>
>     omxplayer /home/pi/video.mov &  
>     exit 0
> }
>
> case "$1" in
>   start|"")
>     do_start
>     ;;
>   restart|reload|force-reload)
>     echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
>     exit 3
>     ;;
>   stop)
>     # No-op
>     ;;
>   status)
>     exit 0
>     ;;
>   *)
>     echo "Usage: asplashscreen [start|stop]" >&2
>     exit 3
>     ;;
> esac
>
> :
> ```
>
> Press ctrl-x, y to confirm saving, and press enter to return to the
>   command line
>
> Now you need to set the file to be executable
>
> ```
> sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/asplashscreen
> ```
>
> And activate it
>
> ```
> sudo insserv /etc/init.d/asplashscreen
> ```
>
> You should now be ready to go!
>
> Reboot your Pi and enjoy the startup movie.

So, I have followed these instructions, step by step, connected via HDMI to TV, but unfortunately, there's a problem:

The splash video is played only after all the boot logs! I mean, I see all the boot logs for about 30-40 seconds (slower than the usual boot), and then when the boot is done, the splash video begins to play, just before the login appears!!

I have used this method, so as to replace the boot logs with a custom splash video, but unfortunately the boot logs still appear on screen.

It's worth mentioning that according to [this](http://blog.sheasilverman.com/2013/09/adding-a-startup-movie-to-your-raspberry-pi/#comment-8183) comment on that website, I also replaced the `quiet` at the the end of the `cmdline.txt` file with `logo.nologo loglevel=3` , but the result is the same. No Difference.

What should I do now !?

Comment: Frankly I doubt that any of these blogs have created a custom splash image or video.  To do that you'd have to recompile the kernel.  All they do is display an image or video as soon as the user can get control, which is many seconds into the boot process.

Comment: Thanks @joan for your comment. Actually, this code is kind of popular, and during my searches, I found it in many websites and forums, including the [rasperrypi.stackexchange.com](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) itself. Besides, many people have reported that this code works perfectly. But I don't know why it doesn't work on my Pi B+.

Comment: When you get it working it would be useful to know the time between on switch and image start.

Comment: Thanks again @joan for your comment. People have reported only a small time (milliseconds maybe) between the on switch and the image start. But I will report it here as well, if I get this to work.

Comment: I did have a look at one linked video and there was a 20 second delay between power on and the video starting,  Given that I've seen people claim they boot the Pi in less than 20 seconds I guess people have different ideas about what boot actually means.

Comment: Well @joan , 20 seconds is not good at all for me. If I had to wait 20 seconds, then I wouldn't need the splash screen at all!! You're right, it doesn't mean boot! So what should I do now? Any other solution?

Comment: Not really, I've never bothered to look into boot images on the Pi.  I don't understand how the screen is written (last screens I used were memory addressed PC types).

Comment: Thanks anyway @joan for your helpful comments. I look forward to any help in this matter.

Comment: You want to do some reading about how services are ordered at boot time using Debian style SysV init.  One place to start is `/etc/init.d/README`.  As is, I don't think that script will produce a predictable start time from one system to another, although it will be consistent once installed.  Obviously you want to tweak it to try for an early slot and re-install.  You could also just manipulate the symlink prefix in `/etc/rcS.d`.

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks for your comment. I will try these, and will let you know the result.

Answer (score 2):

Please change `console=tty1` to `console=tty3`. So the boot logs are shown in tty3 (while boot change with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) and tty1 stays empty while boot process.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange.  Does this actually *work for you*?